# What and how method used for doing multi vendor payments in paypal

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to add Paypal to my website. My website is a multivendor site. But the order is placed for one vendor at a time. But some amount of total amount transferred to admin account also.

I have looked adaptive payment method for this, but it working for the US accounts only(I think).

So what method I have to use for my website for accepting payments by vendors(can be outside the US) with Paypal.

I have looked so many articles for this but not found any working solution.

Thanks